# Use property value in another property setter

Tags: c#, properties, .net-3.5

In my `Class` i need to set one `property` value according to another:

```
public class Quantities
{
    private int _quant;
    public int Quant
    {
        get { return _quant; }
        set
        {
            if (Unit == "K")
            {
                _quant = value / 1000;
            }
            else
            {
                _quant = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
}
```

according to several tests i made it works fine but i still don't know if it's safe to do this.
is it possible that the `Quant Property` will be evaluated before the `Unit Property` or does the compiler (or JIT) knows that it should assign the `Unit Property` first?

Comment: I'll define a method to return the value. or always remember to set `Unit` before you set `Quant`.

Comment: I really wouldn't go down this road. Have a consistent unit (which is NOT settable) and two different methods to set the value. Otherwise what does it mean if you set `Quant` and *then* change `Unit`? It's also very confusing if you make a property so that after you set it to X, it isn't equal to X. Use properly named methods to do that kind of thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the compiler or the JIT. **Your** code assigns the values. **You** need to know the order in which they should be assigned.

BTW: Your code exhibits [temporal coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/). It would be better to make at least the `Unit` unchangeable by making the property `readonly` and by providing a constructor that requires the unit:

```
public class Quantities
{
    private readonly string _unit;
    private int _quant;

    public Quantities(string unit)
    {
        if(unit == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("unit");
        _unit = unit;
    }

    public int Quant
    {
        get { return _quant; }
        set
        {
            if (Unit == "K")
            {
                _quant = value / 1000;
            }
            else
            {
                _quant = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public string Unit { get { return _unit; } }
}
```

This class now can't be used in an incorrect way.

For more points that can be improved with your class, please refer to [Lasse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16936509/572644).

Answer (score 7):

Code on the outside of this class must know about this dependency or you risk someone changing `Unit` without re-setting `Quant`:

```
var x = new Quantities(); // why no constructor for this?
x.Unit = "K";
x.Quant = 1700;           // why int? this will now be 1, not 1.7
x.Unit = "M";
```

*Personally* I would make the class a struct, and make it immutable:

```
public struct Quantity
{
    private readonly double _Value;
    private readonly string _Unit;

    public Quantity(double value, string unit)
    {
        _Value = value;
        _Unit = unit;
    }

    public double Value
    {
        {
            return _Value;
        }
    }

    public double Unit
    {
        {
            return _Unit;
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that I did not change the value at all, hence:

```
var x = new Quantity(1700, "K");
```

means 1700K, not 1.7K. I would refrain from doing such "automagical" interpretations of data. If you need to display the value with a different unit, I would instead build in a conversion system:

```
    public Quantity ConvertToUnit(string newUnit)
    {
        var newValue = ... calculate value with new unit
        return new Quantity(newValue, newUnit);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The class is not a good design. Do not do this.

Consider the following code:

```
Quantities q1 = new Quantities { Unit = "K", Quant = 1000};
Console.WriteLine(q1.Quant); // Prints 1

// Make a copy of q1

Quantities q2 = new Quantities{ Unit = q1.Unit, Quant = q1.Quant };
Console.WriteLine(q2.Quant); // Prints 0
```

You would expect that making a copy of the Quantities would work by doing a basic copy like the above. That it does not shows you how dangerous this kind of design is.

**This is still a problem after making the changes in the accepted answer above**

If you use the changes that Daniel suggested, you still have the nastyness associated with your property setter and getter not being commutative. Sure, you would be forced to pass the units into the constructor, but the object copy still won't work as the user might expect:

```
Quantities q1 = new Quantities("K"){ Quant = 1000};
Console.WriteLine(q1.Quant); // Prints 1

// Make a copy of q1

Quantities q2 = new Quantities(q1.Unit){ Quant = q1.Quant };
Console.WriteLine(q2.Quant); // STILL Prints 0
```